# How to solve the following error running rmcorr in R: Error in get(Participant, dataset) : object 'Subject 1' not found?

Tags: r, correlation

I have the data in long format, with subject, week, measure1, and measure2. There are about 30 repeating measures per subject. I want to run rmcorr to see if there is a correlation between measure1 and measure2 across all subjects. I used the code:

```
rmcorr(participant, measure1, measure2, data)
```

I get

> Error in get(Participant, dataset) : object 'Subject 1' not found

Subject 1 is the first subject in the data, and there are about 300 subjects total.

Answer (score 0):

Is data$participant is a character type?
Try converting it to a factor then running rmcorr again

```
data$participant <- as.factor(data$participant)
```